# Python Newbie hello world (Why???)

Tags: python

Why do I get a syntax error from `print "Hello World"` in Python 3.2?

Comment: Were you following a tutorial or just trying to do hello world? If you were following a python 3.2 tutorial, I would think it would show the proper print() syntax

Comment: The example you've given is perfectly valid for all versions of Python prior to version 3.0; In classic Python print was a statement rather than a function.  In Python 3.0 and later print is a function, and thus requires that you enclose its argument list in paretheses.  In fact the only way that Python's interpreter knows that it should treat a word as a callable object (function, method, class instantiation, etc) is by the presences of the subsequent () expression.  The old treatment of print, as a statement, was a wart and one that Guido had wanted to remove for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
print("Hello World")
```

That is a Python 3 command, while

```
print "Hello World"
```

is a Python 2 command

If the book that you are using only has Python 2 things, get a new book!

Comment: Neither is a "command". They are a function and a statement, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3.2, `print` is a function.

```
print("Hello World")
```

Comment: @Elliot: The other thing. A statement.

Comment: @Makoto "merely" a statement :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville A statement.